# C# running exe inside panel

Tags: c#

I am trying to open a compiled exe inside a panel of my code and that this program stays only inside this panel, in other words, if i move the window or even if I close the window, it would act as the same program.
It's working to some programs for example, "notepad.exe", but some others it doesn't (calc.exe for example it doesn't), they just insist to open outside the panel, so that's when I need help.

That's my code so far:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
        [DllImport("USER32.dll")]
        private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process process = Process.Start("calc.exe");
            process.WaitForInputIdle();
            SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, this.panel1.Handle);
            MoveWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, this.Width - 90, this.Height, true);
        }
    }
```

I am a true newbie on C# and the progress I got so far was from some videos from youtube and even here, but it doesn't work exactly as I need, so I don't mind to reformulate the whole code, as long it works as only 1 program.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't what you want to hear, but this is a really bad idea and I don't recommend trying to host another EXE inside a panel.

Comment: I'd agree. I generally fix my applications so that they retain the last position and size they were at, so you'd be out of luck trying to put them inside your app.

Comment: The exe I want to "put" inside the panel is not possible to resize and I also see that it always opens at the center of the screen, the only thing to fix in this case would be to open within the panel of my program.